# Using chrome.storage inside React app causes Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid context type provided error

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get local storage data inside a Chrome extension which is React add compiled with Webpack:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("tasks").then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

And it causes this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid context type provided.
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ App.js:2
```

But it is accessible:

```
console.log(chrome.storage.local);
```

prints:

```
{get: ƒ, set: ƒ, remove: ƒ, clear: ƒ, getBytesInUse: ƒ, …}
```

Comment: A similar error occurs in a content script after reloading/updating the extension. The solution is to manually unregister all DOM listeners, [example](/a/57471345).

Comment: @wOxxOm so weird, because I was reloading consoles as well... but u are right, it was the case, u can put it as answer and I will accept it.